# conversion of cmisobject to json using java to perform operations in Alfresco Repository

Tags: java, json, alfresco, opencmis

I have a requirement where i need to convert the cmisobject retrieved from Alfresco repository into json. How do i go about it ?

```
Folder root = session.getRootFolder();
        ItemIterable<CmisObject> children = root.getChildren();
        List<Object> folderlist=new ArrayList();
        for (CmisObject o : children) {

          //need to convert o into a json object    
          System.out.println(json);

        }
```

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ ?

Comment: I would look at [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), I have succesfully implemented it in one of my  AMP, you can easily convert map, object, etc. to a Json object.

Comment: If what you want is JSON, why aren't you just using the JSON (Browser) CMIS binding? That'd give you a JSON response natively!

Comment: @Gagravarr:Where can i find reference about using the JSON (Browser) CMIS binding

Comment: You could [start here in the CMIS specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/os/CMIS-v1.1-os.html#x1-120005), or [here in the Alfresco CMIS docs](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/pra/1/concepts/cmis-1.1-browser-binding.html) (amongst many others!)

Comment: @Mardoz:Its throwing circular reference error.